# What type of index should I to add on a multiple request_id in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Data are taking too much time to load when I am searching with specified date. In my project has two table, In one table has unique entries and I added unique index to "request_id" and primary index to auto incremented "id" . another table have multiple records with request_id and in that I added only a primary index to auto incremented "id". Now I am to search these all record through join in both table to check the count for a every "request_id".
I am using below query:-

```
SELECT 
       m.id,m.request_id as id,count(m.request_id) as count,m.reqtype,m.request_time,w.status as status,w.updated_time as updated_time,w.reg_date as reg_date
                FROM 
                    multi_requests m JOIN unique w ON m.request_id = w.request_id 
                WHERE
                    m.request_time

                Between
                    '2015-07-05'
                AND
                    '2015-07-06' 
                GROUP BY
                    m.request_id
                ORDER BY 
                    m.id asc
                LIMIT 
                    0,10" ;
```

I also try to add index to "request_id" in multi_requests table. But when I am adding Index to "request_id" and searching with above query its not showing any type of records on UI.

In multi_requests table has total records = 6033030.
So please suggest me..

Comment: mysql and sql-server are incompatible,pick one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  your query:

```
SELECT m.id, m.request_id as id, count(m.mac_address) as count, m.reqtype, 
       m.request_time, w.status as status, w.updated_time as updated_time,
       w.reg_date as reg_date
FROM multi_requests m JOIN
     unique w
     ON m.mac_address = w.mac_address 
WHERE m.request_time Between '2015-07-05' AND '2015-07-06' 
GROUP BY m.request_id
ORDER BY m.id asc
LIMIT 0, 10 ;
```

It is a bit strange, because you have a ton of columns in the `select`, but only one in the `group by`.  Let me assume that you know what you are doing.

For this query, the best indexes are on `multi_requests(request_time, mac_address, request_id)` and `unique(mac_address)`.

Comment: Actually I am to show report on UI of all records that's why I use a ton of columns in the select.

Comment: I add unique index to mac_address in the table "unique"  but I unable to understand now what type of index I should add on other column multi_requests(request_time,mac_address, request_id) as you show in comment

Comment: sorry I done a mistake in my post so now i edited  my post with  request_id instead of mac_address

Comment: Thank you for your answer @GordenLinoff